# Ответ на вопрос Кто...

Tags: общие-вопросы

Предполагает ли вопрос "Кто из русских писателей был отправлен в ссылку?" перечисление всех удостоившихся этой сомнительной чести?

Comment: А  почему  сомнительной ?

Answer (score 1):

Да, подобная формулировка предполагает перечисление всех писателей отправленных в ссылку. Правда вопрос без описания, что подразумевается под "ссылкой", а что под "писателем", мягко говоря некорректен.

Человек, написавший пару эпиграмм - писатель?  А условный Ленин, писавший лишь не художественные произведения? А если человека сперва сослали, а потом он стал известным писателем (Достоевский)? А если  не сослали, а на каторгу? А если в тюрьму или того паче казнили? А высылка из страны - ссылка? А вынужденная эмиграция? В общем вопросов больше, чем ответов.

Answer (score 0):

Я полагаю что зависит от содержания. "Кто из них умеет рисовать?" просит перечислить всех, но "кто из них лучше всего рисует?", конечно, спрашивает только об одном человеке.

На данный вопрос можно ответить и так, и так, в разных ситуациях. Я бы перечислила всех. Мне кажется, что больше клонится всё-таки на сторону перечисления, не примера.